# Unable to break up a Doctrine ODM Query

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

SO I have the following Mongo ODM query that works just fine:

```
      $query = $dm->createQueryBuilder('MainClassifiedBundle:Listing')
         ->select('id', 'title', 'assets')
         ->field('somefield0')->equals($somefield)
         ->field('somefield')->equals($blah)
         ->field('somefield2')->range($minPrice, $maxPrice)
         ->field('somefield3')->near($latitude, $longitude)
         ->getQuery();

 $my_data = $query->execute();
```

However if I try to break it up like the following:

```
 $query = $dm->createQueryBuilder('MainClassifiedBundle:Listing')
     ->select('id', 'title', 'assets')
     ->field('somefield0')->equals($somefield)
     ->field('somefield')->equals($blah);

if ($propertyType != 'All') {
     $query->field('someothercrazyfield')->equals($somethingelse);

     $query->field('somefield2')->range($minPrice, $maxPrice)
     ->field('somefield3')->near($latitude, $longitude)
     ->getQuery();

 $my_data = $query->execute();
```

I get an error that method execute does not exist.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are not storing the query when you call getQuery(). I've changed your example below.

```
$query = $dm->createQueryBuilder('MainClassifiedBundle:Listing')
    ->select('id', 'title', 'assets')
    ->field('somefield0')->equals($somefield)
    ->field('somefield')->equals($blah);

if ($propertyType != 'All') {
    $query->field('someothercrazyfield')->equals($somethingelse);

    $query->field('somefield2')->range($minPrice, $maxPrice)
       ->field('somefield3')->near($latitude, $longitude);
}

$my_data = $query->getQuery()->execute();
```